# My Wallet file got erased and I had a transaction done. Can I recover those bitcoins with transaction ID?

Tags: transactions, wallet.dat

I am a first time user I had gotten a transaction done before but my pc suffered systwem failure and I had to reinstall windows, obviously had to reinstall my bitcoin wallet software, but I had some money in it and I dont know if there is any way to get that back, I do have the transaction Id for that, id there any way to recover thse bitcoins?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot recover your Bitcoin with only the transaction ID.
If you are lucky, the data has not been overwritten yet and you can recover it with certain tools. It depends on the amount of Bitcoin you lost and if you think it's worth the try.
I hope this helps: https://www.easeus.com/resource/recover-files-after-reinstalling-windows.htm

Good luck. You'll need it...